# Coffee and argon/nitrogen

Tags: everyday-chemistry, food-chemistry

I’ve recently been experimenting blanketing coffee with argon and nitrogen. I’m finding that argon has a more positive result. I can’t find any data or information that would confirm this other then taste! Can anyone help me to determine why argon is better to use with roasted coffee? I know argon is less reactive to other things then nitrogen. But is that anything backed up with data including some that is relatable to coffee?

Comment: To clarify - you are blanketing roasted coffee beans inside a closed container with argon and nitrogen, separately. Do you know what else (if anything) is in the argon and nitrogen you are using?

Comment: Argon 'has a more positive result' in what measurable way?

Comment: Argon normally comes in cylinders with a purity ranging from 4.8 to 6.0, which means from 99.998% to 99.9999%. Nitrogen can come in cylinders with similar purities, but it can also come from a nitrogen membrane system which yields purities between 95 and 99%. This last one is then only 2.0. If coffee is very sensitive to oxygen, this 1 to 5% could make a difference.

Comment: @JonCuster The OP says that it is the taste. It is not a conventional analytical instrument, but I know that in the perfumery industry there are employed people for their noses, wich are more accurate then GLC in detecting differences.

Comment: @RaoulKessels - perhaps, although the question is not clearly worded about that point. A wine or perfume expert would be able to clearly describe what was different between two samples, not just say that the taste or smell had a more positive result.